# Send alert to configurable group in Splunk

Tags: splunk

This is the first time I am using Splunk. I need to create a real time alert which runs every 15 seconds, then sends one alert email to a configurable group of people.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How can I create a script that send email to a list of persons ?

Answer (score 0):

Splunk helpfully provides with an option to send a triggered alert to a single or multiple recipients. Sending an alert every 15 seconds sounds a little extreme and may possibly need to be reviewed (but that's another story :)).

This [link](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.5.3/Alert/Alertexamples) provides a nice example on how to create scheduled alerts.

Alternatively, you may also send a notification from the search command using:

```
index=main | head 5 | sendemail to=<email address> server=<server info> subject="Here is an email notification" message="This is an example message" sendresults=true inline=true format=raw sendpdf=true
```

Or if you fancy getting a little creative, you can send an email to different recipients depending on your search output:

```
"error" | stats count | eval recipient=case(count > 3500, "recipient1@domain.com", count >= 500, "recipient2@domain.com", 1==1, null()) | where isnotnull(recipient)
```

When the search is saved as an alert, configure the *'Send email alert'* action with the following token in the *'To'* recipient field.

```
$result.recipient$
```